# java.io.FileNotFoundException: localhost/broadcast_1

Tags: java, apache-spark, filenotfoundexception, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a spark application using sparkSQL inside, but whenever i use LEFT OUTER JOIN its giving me following error,

`select a.name,b.phone FROM name a LEFT OUTER JOIN phone b ON (a.id=b.id)`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: localhost:57067/broadcast_1
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast$.read(HttpBroadcast.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast.readObject(HttpBroadcast.scala:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

But there is no problem for me if i use JOIN instead of it. What will be the issue ? 
I am using Spark Version 1.0.0

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally file not found exception are seen when there is issue in finding file during file operation. And if the SQL statement is the culprit of your exception you should have got SQlException, are you doing any file operations before doing the SQL operation.